# How can I create a new file every time I run the program using Java

Tags: java, xml, csv

Below is the code that I have worked on, It basically traverse folders and extracts data from the xml files and outputs the data into a CSV file. All of this works. But I would like to create new output csv file every time i run the program. I would appreciate if you guys can provide some examples or modify the code which i have worked on. Please I have been trying to figure out the solution from some hours now.

```
public class MergeCode1 {

    public void walk(String path,Boolean is_parent) throws Exception {
        File filePath = new File ("C:/Users/Vishvesh Savant/Desktop/Mirriad/");
        System.out.println(filePath);


        File root = new File(path); //Input File Path
        File[] list = root.listFiles();

        while(is_parent == false);
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int value;
            value=rand.nextInt(50)+1;
            filePath = new File (("C:/Users/Vishvesh Savant/Desktop/Mirriad/"+"new_one"+value+".csv"));
        }
        try{
            if (list == null) return;
            System.out.println("2");

            for (File f : list ) {
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbfactory = null;
                DocumentBuilder dbuilder = null;
                Document doc = null;

                if (f.isDirectory()) {
                    walk(f.getPath(),false);
                    System.out.println( "Dir:" + f.getAbsolutePath());
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println( "File:" + f.getAbsolutePath());
                    dbfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    dbuilder = dbfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    doc =  dbuilder.parse(f.getAbsolutePath());
                    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                    NodeList list1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("product");                   
                    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath, true);

//                  String Fileheader="uid,title";
//                  fileWriter.append(Fileheader.toString());
//                  fileWriter.append("\n");

                    for(int i=0; i<list1.getLength();i++){
                        Node node = list1.item(i);
                        if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                            Element element = (Element) node;
                            fileWriter.append(element.getAttribute("uid"));
                            System.out.println(element.getAttribute("uid"));
                            fileWriter.append(",");
                            fileWriter.append( element.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent());
                            System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent());
                            fileWriter.append(",");
                            fileWriter.append( element.getElementsByTagName("actor").item(0).getTextContent());
                            System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("actor").item(0).getTextContent());
                            fileWriter.append(",");
                            fileWriter.append( element.getElementsByTagName("director").item(0).getTextContent());
                            System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("director").item(0).getTextContent());
                            fileWriter.append(",");
                            fileWriter.append( element.getElementsByTagName("country").item(0).getTextContent());
                            System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("country").item(0).getTextContent());
                            fileWriter.append(",");
                            fileWriter.append( element.getElementsByTagName("format").item(0).getTextContent());
                            System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("format").item(0).getTextContent());
                            fileWriter.append(",");
                            fileWriter.append( element.getElementsByTagName("bitrate").item(0).getTextContent());
                            System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("bitrate").item(0).getTextContent());
                            fileWriter.append(",");
                            fileWriter.append( element.getElementsByTagName("fps").item(0).getTextContent());
                            System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("fps").item(0).getTextContent());
                            fileWriter.append(",");
                            fileWriter.append( element.getElementsByTagName("aspect").item(0).getTextContent());
                            System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("aspect").item(0).getTextContent());
                            fileWriter.append(",");
                            fileWriter.append( element.getElementsByTagName("width").item(0).getTextContent());
                            System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("width").item(0).getTextContent());
                            fileWriter.append(",");
                            fileWriter.append(element.getBaseURI());
                            fileWriter.append(element.getAttribute("uid"));
                            fileWriter.append(element.getElementsByTagName("format").item(0).getTextContent());

                            fileWriter.append("\n");

                            //fileWriter.flush();
                            fileWriter.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error!!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        MergeCode1 fw = new MergeCode1();
        fw.walk("C:/Users/Vishvesh Savant/Desktop/Mirriad/Test",true);  
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `is_parent`? In what way doesn't your present code satisfy the requirement? Do you realise you have an erroneous `;` in your `while` loop?

Comment: yes I had removed the while loop in my latest effort. 
"is_parent" is basically my "public void walk" and the child method is "walk(f.getPath(),false)". I had created a flag to check when the parent call is made and when the child call is made. So when the program runs the first time the "parent" will be called in this case a new csv file will be created.

Problem:
I am not able to create a new csv every time i run the program, After my new changes a new csv gets created for every record the program retrieves from a xml file which are located in different folders. Which is incorrect.

Comment: If you want a solution for your latest effort, you have to post your latest effort. Surely this is obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand you, you want to put all records of one call to walk from main into the same file; the way to do this is to create the filePath of the CSV outside the walk method (in your case in main) and change the method signature to:

```
public void walk(String path,Boolean is_parent, String filePath) throws Exception {
```

Then you have the same filename for all calls - also for your sub-directories... assuming you also pass it to the reflective calls (I believe that is your intention - right?)

Comment: Your answer gave me the thought to change the code. Made some changes and added some functions and Now the program creates new csv file after every execution of the program manually.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this line:

```
filePath = new File (("C:/Users/Vishvesh Savant/Desktop/Mirriad/"+"new_one"+value+".csv"));
```

You can use:

```
File filePath = File.createTempFile("out_", ".csv", new File("C:/Users/Vishvesh Savant/Desktop/Mirriad/"));
```

This will genereate uniqe filename in given dir with prefix "out_" and suffix ".csv".

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.currentTimeMillis()` :

```
long value;
value = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: This would just give me the time, I dont think would solve the problem

Comment: Since it returns different value every time it is called, you will have different file names. You may rarely have duplicate file names if you change your system time or if you run multiple instances of your program. In such cases you need to check the existence of your file before creating it.

Comment: If you want to make 100% sure that the file does not exist you should use exists method of File class.

Comment: Thanks.. Used the code given by you in my final program.

Answer (score 0):

Used the "Create" function to store value and then appended that value in the Main method. Create gets called every time when the program is run there by creating a new csv file with the records.

```
public void clean(FileWriter fileWriter) throws IOException{
        fileWriter.append("\n");
        fileWriter.flush();
        fileWriter.close();
    }

public static long create(){
        long value;
        value = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        long value = create();
        File filePath = new File ("G:/Mirriad/test_"+value+".csv");
        String Fileheader="UID,TITLE,ACTOR,DIRECTOR,COUNTRY,FORMAT,BITRATE,FRAMES_PER_SHIFT,ASPECT,WIDTH,PATH";
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath, true);
        fileWriter.append(Fileheader.toString());

        MergeCode1 fw = new MergeCode1();
        String path = "G:/Mirriad/ScriptTest";

        fw.create();
        System.out.println(fw.create());
        fw.walk(path, filePath, fileWriter);
        fw.clean(fileWriter);   
    }
```